# Laravel - Check if user is already followed

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if a user is already following another user,

in my database i have:

```
user_id     follow_id   
1               2
1               3
1               4
1               5
```

Now lets say that user 1 is not following user 6, how can i check this? 
Or how can I check if a user is already followed?

Comment: Please, read more about relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

It will help u with your task

Comment: I think you should try as `DB::table('tablename')->where('user_id' , Auth::user()->id)->get();`   It will give you all users who are followed by user who have id 1

Comment: i am giving you some suggestion.. read carefully.. first you get records of user follow (select * from follow where user_id=$userid).... second when you echo "follow" or "not follow" then you can try this.. if(!in_array($value->user_id, $follow_data)){echo 'follow' else echo 'not follow'}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you're using eloquent.

```
// Add these to your User model
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follows', 'follow_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function isFollowing(User $user)
{
    return !! $this->following()->where('follow_id', $user->id)->count();
}

public function isFollowedBy(User $user)
{
    return !! $this->followers()->where('user_id', $user->id)->count();
}

// Make the check
$user = User::findOfFail(1);
$checkUser = User::findOfFail(6);

if ($user->isFollowing($checkUser)) {
    // Following
} else {
    // Not following
}
```

This also makes it to follow and unfollow users. If you want the full implementation with example then check out the following link.

https://github.com/gothinkster/laravel-realworld-example-app/blob/master/app/RealWorld/Follow/Followable.php

Comment: We can use exists() instead of using count() and casting the returned value to boolean by !!